# Connecting to another server from the xslt stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, ldap-query

Good Morning,

I wrote a stylesheet, for my LDAP query, to connect to a folder that has photos in it. It was on the same server, which made it easier to connect, but now that folder is located on another server. I am having a problem writing the new path to connect to the same folder on another server.

The original query allowed me to connect to our photo folder on the same server. The concat allowed us to pull an ID number that matched the photo with the ID as a name. This worked just fine.

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<!-- Parameters assigned at runtime. -->
<xsl:param name="paramCurrentTimestamp">20001231173010</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="paramCurrentDT" >12/31/2000 5:30:10 PM</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="paramCurrentCulture">en-US</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="PrimaryPortraitImageFile">
<xsl:copy>
**<xsl:value-of select="concat('E:\MyPhoto\Upload\Approved\',.)" />**
</xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

<!-- The transformation below provides trivial default copy of everything. -->
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>
<!-- End of customizable area. -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, the image path has changed. The server name is cld-prd-app2. The transmission port is 14333. User name xxxx Password xxxx. I tried this and it did not work. What am I missing? Thank you for your time.

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<!-- Parameters assigned at runtime. -->
<xsl:param name="paramCurrentTimestamp">20001231173010</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="paramCurrentDT" >12/31/2000 5:30:10 PM</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="paramCurrentCulture">en-US</xsl:param>



<xsl:template match="PrimaryPortraitImageFile">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:value-of select="**concat('\\cld-prd-app2\E:\Photos\Approved\',.)" />**
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- The transformation below provides trivial default copy of everything. -->
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>
<!-- End of customizable area. -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What error happens? I would believe a network mapped drive is valid only to the user. The code could be running as some other user or sys Admin account.

Comment: This is not about the XSLT transformation but the correct value you place in the result document. That really depends on the vocabulary of the result document. The identity transformation sugest that it's the same from the input source. That's a key information.

Comment: Hmmm. The error message I get is " Invalid match criteria for object type 'Personnel' (Matching is not unique). Receiving the data from LDAP, I matched the ID to match the ID number  located in a SQL server and where the photos are located. It worked when everything was on the same server. Since the photo folder moved to another server, I keep getting this error. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Alejandro. I am not understanding what you mean. Can you break it down for me? Thank you

Comment: Is E: a physical drive or a virtual device?

Comment: Yes. If you were transforming to an HTML document, the source attribute of an image element must follow the [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/index.html) and subsequently [RFC3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) and [RFC3987](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3987)

Comment: E is on a virtual drive.